# How to use unison-jz inside a bash script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, version, snap, unison

`unison-jz` works well on a bash command-line but not inside a script. It seems that inside the script, it falls back to the regular `unison` command. Can someone tell me how to use `unison-jz` inside a bash script?

---

I had the `unison` version conflict that is described in [#583058](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583058) and the proposed solution for ubuntu works fine on an interactive shell.

However, I want to do the same from inside a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
unison profile_name -sshargs '-i ~/.ssh/privatekey'
```

This is a MWE version of the `script.sh` (in reality the script is more copmlex, but I checked this MWE and it shows the same faulty behaviour). When I invoke this script from the same command line as before (but also from another shell), it seems that inside the script, the regular `unison` version is used instead of the snapped `unison-jz` (which is used when invoking from the interactive shell). Hence, the syncing fails with the same *Fatal error* as before, saying "This can happen because you have different versions of Unison installed on the client and server machines", which I had fixed with the above approached.

How can I make the shell script use the snapped `unison-jz` version instead of unison?

Both client and server use bash shell on ubuntu (client: 20.04, server: 18.04).

---

What I've done on the command-line:

1. Install snap:

   `sudo snap install --devmode unison-jz`
2. Add this line to my unison profile file:

   `servercmd = /snap/bin/unison-jz.unison -ui text`
3. Comment out line 19 in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` so that is looks like

   `# Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf`
4. Execute unison:

   `unison profile_name -sshargs '-i ~/.ssh/privatekey'`

This works fine from an interactive `bash` shell.

Comment: Have you tried running the path explicitly in the script? e.g. ``/snap/bin/unison-jz.unison -ui text profile_name -sshargs '-i ~/.ssh/privatekey'``?

Comment: If I do that, it tells me that `/home/username/snap/unison-jz/19/.unison//home/username/.unison/profile_name.prf`, even if I explicitly give it the profile path as `/home/username/.unison/profile_name.prf`

Comment: I meant to use the command explicit but not ``profile_name``.  A unison quirk requires that be installed in the correct dir and typed with no extension.  I poked at my problems more since I made this comment.  The snap package requires you do everything inside of their walled garden, making issues like this pop up.  e.g., don't use default ``.unison`` paths.  I ended up compiling and installing from ``opam`` rather than deal with the snap package problems.  I recommend it.